# Is there differering mathematical notation for indirect vs direct causes in proofs?

Tags: logic, notation

I know that in logical notation, causes can be notated with $\to$. It could be useful to differentiate between indirect and direct causes in a proof. For example if A directly causes B and B directly causes C, then A indirectly causes C. This could be written $\Big(( A\to B) \land (B \to C) \Big) \implies (A \to C)$
However this can potentially cause confusion due to the arrows used for direct and indirect causes being the same.

Comment: Those are implications rather than causes

Comment: To expand on Hagen's comment, logical implication $A\to B$ simply means that every time $A$ is true, $B$ is also true. There may be no causal relationship between them.

Comment: I know that dispite their similarities, they are still different mathematically, What would be a better way for me to write them?

Comment: Modal connectives such as "causes" are interesting, but are not used in mathematics.

Comment: Ok. So pretty much using $\to$ sounds like my best option as there is no actual symbol for causation.

Comment: Although I suppose that to represent causation, I could use $A_{t1}\to B_{t2}$ and explain that $A_{t1}$ is a bolean function representing whether a is true at $time = t_1$ and $B_{t2}$ likewise for $time = t_2$.

Comment: I am sure that some logicians/philosophers have attempted to construct a theory involving causation, but it's not mainstream in mathematics. A very brief Google search turned up this paper http://www.hit.ac.il/acc/bochmana/7.pdf which also has references to other work in the area.